# Listening for BlueTooth state Changes with React-Native - Android

Tags: react-native

I am working with a team of React-Native JS developers who asked me to give them a native module for listening for Bluetooth state changes.

I created a ReactMethod that takes a Callback:

```
 @ReactMethod
public void registerForBlueToothStateChanges(Callback listener){
    mainActivity = (MainActivity)getCurrentActivity();
    mainActivity.registerBTStateChangeListener(listener);
}
```

This method essentially is designed to set a Callback that will be used by my broadcast Receiver and at the same time send the current Bluetooth state back to the call back.. That all works fine, but in my Actual BroadCast Receiver i get an error: "The callback registerForBlueToothStateChanges() exists in module TripManager, but only one callback maybe registered to a function in a native Module"

Main Activity Relative Code:

```
@Subscribe
    public void onBluetoothStateChanged(BluetoothStateChange state){
        //check against current state to avoid duplicate offs
        Log.v(TAG, "STATE CHANGED WOOT");
        if(!state.equals(lastBluetoothState)){
            lastBluetoothState = state;
            Log.v(TAG, "BT STATE CHANGE***: "+state +" "+state.equals(BluetoothStateChange.ON));
            if(blueToothStateListener != null) {
                int i = 0;
                if (state.equals(BluetoothStateChange.ON)) {
                    i = 1;
                }
                sendBTStateChange(i);
            }
        }
        lastBluetoothState = state;
    }

    public void registerBTStateChangeListener(Callback listener){
        blueToothStateListener = listener;
        int i = 0;
        if(lastBluetoothState.equals(BluetoothStateChange.ON)){
           i = 1;
        }
        sendBTStateChange(i);
    }

    private void sendBTStateChange(int code){
        blueToothStateListener.invoke(code);
    }
```

Any pointers how i can get around this?